# Is there a way to prevent pulseaudio sink indexes to change?

Tags: linux, bash, pulseaudio

I want to bind a key to change my current sink in use, for that I would need the sink index. Thing is that it keeps changing on every restart, so I would need a way to prevent my sink indexes from changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you check the manpage or help for whatever command you intend to use and see if the Sink name can be used instead of the index number